# Adding custom colors to Color struct?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, colors, struct

Is it Possible to add to the list of Colors in .NET? for example Color.Red Color.Green etc... already exist, but I want to add more colors like Color.SlightlyDarkGray for example...

EDIT:
I need this so I can make default colors for my custom user control instead of retyping 245,65,65 or whatever each time that i change the default color i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement Jon Skeet's idea like this

```
public struct MoreColors // or public static class
{
    public static Color SomeNiceColor { get { return Color.FromArgb(12,136,20); } }
    public static Color MyPreferredColor { get { return Color.FromArgb(209,80,0); } }
}
```

Since C# 6.0, you can use [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) properties. They are identical semantically, just with a simpler syntax.

```
public struct MoreColors 
{
    public static Color SomeNiceColor => Color.FromArgb(12,136,20);
    public static Color MyPreferredColor => Color.FromArgb(209,80,0);
}
```

Somewhat more efficient is the approach of using [auto-implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) read-only properties with an initializer (since C# 6.0 as well), since they will be initialized only once, even when accessed several times:

```
public struct MoreColors 
{
    public static Color SomeNiceColor { get; } = Color.FromArgb(12,136,20);
    public static Color MyPreferredColor { get; } =  Color.FromArgb(209,80,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No - all the fields in `Color` are already there; you can't add anything to the type.

You could always create your *own* type called something like `MoreColors` though. Obviously that wouldn't affect what's shown in the designer if that's what you were interested in.

Comment: is there a way to inherit from Color and then define a few extras there, and use that struct instead?

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu: No - you can't derive from a struct. It's still not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu: Actually the same Jon suggests. It will be your own class, but not the `Color` with *your fields*.

Comment: ah ok, i updated the question, and right now im trying to see if i can get Tigran's suggestion to work

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. You *could* think of adding an `extension method`, but it would be (if would be) only a method and *not* static *field*, as it's in native class.